# How to Solve Error CS1525 Invalid expresion Term ")"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AOpening : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ThePlayer;
    public GameObject FadeScene;
    public GameObject TextBox;

    void Start()
    {
        ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPerson - AIO> ().enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(ScenePlayer());
    }

    IEnumerator ScenePlayer()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        FadeScene.SetActive(false);
        TextBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = "I need to get out of here.";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        TextBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
        ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

> Error CS1525 (15,46)

Could someone help me please? I don't know what I've done wrong

Comment: "ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPerson - AIO> ().enabled = false;" you can't have a class with space

Comment: Ive solved i othervise but thanks for your hint

Comment: I'm assuming that this is the line with the error (the code makes no sense): `ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPerson - AIO> ().enabled = false;`.  In the future, don't just give the error message, point out which line is the one that causes it, please.

Comment: There is no explanation as for what you are trying to achieve, no context just the code and the error message. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

The first line after in the Start function had the wrong class name on the GetComponent. It most likely should be `ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = false;` there instead